# __construct() in L4 controller not working

Tags: php, laravel-4

I know how to use the `filter` in l4 however i just want to know why this code is not working.

```
class CustomController extends BaseController
{
     public function __construct()
     {
          if(!Session::has('certain_id'))
             return 'You are not allowed here';
     }

     public function getAdd()
     {
          return 'You can add here and im sure you have that "certain_id"';
     }
}
```

in my routes.php:

```
Route::controller('custom','CustomController');
```

Im very sure that `certain_id` is not define in the session but it always continue until `getAdd` method. I also tried removing the `if` statement but same result.

Comment: `public function getAdd` <- is a typo?

Comment: oh sorry for that. its now fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that php [__construct()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) method doesn't have a return value (see, **void**):

```
 void __construct ([ mixed $args [, $... ]] )
```

That means your `return '...'` is simply ignored, so when you call the `getAdd()` method you're right in saying that the __construct() is called (a new instance of the class is created), but then the processing goes on to the method.

I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but if it's some login filtering you could do

```
 public function __construct()
 {
      if(!Session::has('certain_id'))
         Response::redirect('login');
 }
```

So that when that `certain_id` is not present you're redirected *outside*, onto **another class**. Be careful not to redirect to the *same* class, otherwise you'll risk a infinite loop (the class is instanciated, the sesssion is not present, you're redirected to a method: a new instance is created, the id is still not present, so you're redirected again, and so on)